# Trigger Destroys the object, but fails to add time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made some changes to my code with no errors the trigger destroy the `timepickup` object but not add the time.
I like to call the function `addtime` or `taketime` and add or subtract when I need with the trigger method.

Here my new code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CountDownTimer : MonoBehaviour {
    float timeRemaining = 60.0f;

    public void addTime()
    {
        timeRemaining += 100.00f;
    }

    public void taketime()
    {
        timeRemaining -= 10.00f;
    }

    void Update () {
        timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        if (timeRemaining > 0) {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(325, 30, 200, 50), 
                    "Time Remaining : " +timeRemaining);
        }
        else {
            Application.LoadLevel("Game Over");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // The switch statement checks what tag the other gameobject is, and reacts accordingly.
        switch (other.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "TimePickup":
                Invoke("addtime", 3f);
                break;
            case "TimeOut":
                Invoke("taketime", 3f);
                break;
        }
        // Finally, this line destroys the gameObject the player collided with.
        Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("TimePickup"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what it is you're trying to accomplish here.  Can you state your problem plainly and clearly?  Code alone rarely explains the problem you're having.

Comment: I Liked To call The function addtime or taketime and add or subtract wen i need with the trigger method. The code there is no errors and it destroy the object timepickup but it not add the time at all.

Comment: The code its supose to add time or subtract this is for the time pickups

Comment: Your code has a method named `addTime`, but in your `OnTriggerEnter` method, in the `"TimePickup"` case, it is trying to invoke `addtime`, which does not exist.  Try `Invoke("addTime")` instead.

Comment: I have try what you say and give me an error

Comment: cs1501 no overload method Invoke take one argument

Comment: What version of the unity library are you using?  5.4?

Comment: my version of unity3d is 5.1.1f

Comment: what is this? // Finally, this line destroys the gameObject the player collided with.
        Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("TimePickup"));

Comment: This Will Destroy The Pickup Time

Comment: To who's collider is the CountDownTimer class attached to?

Comment: well the countdownTimer is atached to the main camera and i have atached to the pickup to because i wanted to try if its work but what i wanted its to get the trigguer in other file to attach to the TimePickup but i am new and i dont know how to add the time to my CountDownTimer.cs the code up

Comment: When you add breakpoints to both invokes, does it break on them? (meaning it actually gets there?)

Comment: No Its seems to nothing append

Comment: well it destroy the pickup but no other

Comment: add a breakpoint on the switch (other.gameObject.tag), is the tag correct?

Comment: Well i have just place like you say and now the errors is gone but it not destroy the object and no time add, i Have check if the box collider is atached to it and is trigger is check and the tag its the same

Answer (score 2):

Is there some reason you need to use Invoke?

Try this instead:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // The switch statement checks what tag the other gameobject is, and reacts accordingly.
        switch (other.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "TimePickup":
                addTime();
                Destroy (other.gameObject);
                break;
            case "TimeOut":
                taketime();
                break;
            default: // Invalid tag, let's hear about it
                Debug.Log("Invalid tag "+other.gameObject.tag);
                break;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: No well a friend here tell me to try it what i want only its to add time to my timeRemain but i have try multiple ways to do but not work. I Liked To Pickup a Timerbox on game and this will add time to my Timer On CountDownTimer.cs

Comment: The Object Its Destroy But No Time add At All

Answer (score 0):

kevin628 answered the question. You have to rename the function call to `Invoke("addTime")`. You got the `no overload method` error because you forgot to add the delay part: Invoke("addTime", **3f**)

Comment: what you mean about rename it i need to rename my addTime function. and well you tell me i forget the delay, sorry for the question but i am new on scripting you mean the 3f On Final?

Comment: The function `Invoke` takes two arguments. First, the function to be called, second, how long to wait before it's called.

Comment: You should either call the function directly, or make sure that you have the name of the function written correctly in the Invoke. Remember that you might get to GameOver because the time is not added before the 3 second delay

Comment: Well In fact wen i call addTime The Trigger destroy the object but not add the time to the timeRemain i have boxcollider and as trigger, i have the right tag but the wen i invoke the addTime Nothing append

Answer (score 0):

Tank you all for your patience i finally get the script work in fact i heaved place the script to the main camera, i just delete this component from the main camera and place at the player and now its work perfect.